# Nexus API - using curl to get specific asset

Tags: api, curl, nexus, nexus3

Using the [Nexus API docs](https://help.sonatype.com/repomanager3/rest-and-integration-api/assets-api) I can retrieve a list of assets within a repository with the following curl command:

```
curl -u user:password -X GET 'https://nexusurl/service/rest/v1/components?repository=docker'
```

How can I get a specific asset? e.g. in the repository 'docker' with the path:

`v2/x/manifests/1.0`

I get a 404 with the following attempt:

```
curl -u user:password -X GET 'https://nexusurl/service/rest/v1/components?repository=docker/v2/x/manifests/1.0'
```

Nexus version: 3.18

Answer (score 1):

You can use the /v1/assets/{id} endpoint once you have the ID from the list.
If this is not sufficient, you either need to have a very specific /v1/search/assets or I suspect what you want is not possible at this time (latest 3.25.1).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, as of now the API doesn't provide a GET by specific path. 
I've found an alternative way to approach my problem which isn't relative to Nexus API so it's probably not worth sharing here. Thanks again